# SQL queries basics - returning multiple data over different dates

Tags: sql

Having trouble with basic sql query, I need to summarize a lot of information and the query i'm using is:

```
SELECT date, id, actions
FROM accounts 
WHERE (date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-9-30') AND (id in (---ids---));
```

Right now I'm getting

```
date 1    id1   actions
date 2    id1   actions
date 3    id1   actions
date 4    id1   actions
date 5    id1   actions
date 6    id1   actions

date 1    id2   actions
date 2    id2   actions
date 3    id2   actions
date 4    id2   actions
date 5    id2   actions
date 6    id2   actions
```

what i want is

```
date 1    id1   actions  id2  actions
date 2    id1   actions  id2  actions
date 3    id1   actions  id2  actions
date 4    id1   actions  id2  actions
date 5    id1   actions  id2  actions
date 6    id1   actions  id2  actions
```

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using a specific SQL server, or asking about SQL in general?

Comment: How do you relate `id1` to `id2`?  Or, how is `id1` and `id2` related to the dates?

Comment: You can use a `PIVOT` to put them into something similar but with `id1` and `id2` as the column names.

Comment: asking about sql in general

Comment: Yeah didn't think about using a pivot table to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is only one `id1` and `id2` on a given date, then this is a pivot query.  There is special syntax in some databases for a pivot, but the following works in general:

```
SELECT date,
       max(case when id = 'id1' then id end) as id1,
       max(case when id = 'id1' then actions end) as id1_actions,
       max(case when id = 'id2' then id end) as id2,
       max(case when id = 'id2' then actions end) as id2_actions
FROM accounts 
WHERE (date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-9-30') AND (id in (---ids---))
group by date
order by date;
```

Note that `date` is a keyword in some databases, so you would need to quote it in some way (such as using double quotes, back quotes, or square brackets).